# Library Import Issue in android

Tags: android, import-libraries

I compiled this new library from komensky for live valiation,everything's seems fine except it shows error on the library import eu.inmite.android.lib.dialogs.SimpleDialogFragment. says that the dialogs can't be resolved. Any help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSaNs.png)

Comment: May be the library is not compiled successfully.

Comment: Did you import the SimpleDialogFragment after compiling library?